# convert a Python timestamp in a list of dictionaries to a date

Tags: python, timestamp

I have a list of dictionaries that contains a Python timestamp. I need to convert the timestamp to a regular date. I was hoping to do this using a lamda expression, but I can't get it to work. See my code below:

```
findMatchPlay(newData):
i = 0
compList=[]
for tPeriod in newData:
    member = tPeriod['username']
    url2 = 'https://api.chess.com/pub/player/{}/matches'.format(member)
    response = s.get(url2)
    response.raise_for_status()
    matches = response.json()
    for status in matches:
        for game in matches[status]:
            gString = ''.join(game['club'])
            if team in gString:
                i = i + 1
        compList.append({'player': member,'Date Joined': tPeriod['Date Joined'],
            'active': tPeriod['active'],
            'status': status, 'games played': i})
        compList[0]['Date Joined'] = compList[0]['Date Joined'].apply(lambda x:datetime.fromtimestamp(x))
        i = 0
```

The above code gives me the following error:  int' object has no attribute 'apply'

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
compList[0]['Date Joined'] = compList[0]['Date Joined']
```

should be

```
compList[0]['Date Joined'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(compList[0]['Date Joined'])
```

Comment: OK, that was a huge help, but I get the following error:  TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime).

Comment: Can you please post the values in tPeriod?

Comment: I tried to correct the error using "int" like this datetime.fromtimestamp(int(compList[0]['Date Joined'])) but that did not work

Comment: No. That would not be proper. I want to know what is the value in compList[0]['Date Joined'].

Comment: tPeriod looks like this:  {'Date Joined': 1547992205, 'active': 'weekly', 'username': 'buffalobill57'}
{'Date Joined': 1547986304, 'active': 'weekly', 'username': 'knightburgler'}

Comment: from datetime import datetime

print datetime.fromtimestamp(1547992205) gives the output 2019-01-20 19:20:05

Comment: The problem happens since in the loop, you are always accessing compList[0]. First time, compList[0]['Date Joined'] gets converted and in the second iteration, it must be complaining that it is not an int. Please check this.

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what the problem is. I think I can work it out from here. Thank you so much Jay!

Comment: Glad it worked. Can you please upvote and accept the answer if it helped. Thanks!